# Left Grill Knobs ON and LP Tank Valve OFF-Why did it mess up the tank where valve screws in?

Tags: equipment

Scenario:  I left the KNOBS on my gas grill in the ON position.  I turned OFF the VALVE on top of the propane tank.

Now when I turn propane tank to ON via the valve on top of it, it spews hissing gas out through the area where the valve screws into the top of the LP tank. It is coming out around the actual threads of that screw in valve.

Someone please explain what might have happened.  Thanks.

(I am going to swap out the tank at the store where I got it, hopefully for free cause it was darn near full, but I am just very curious about what happened.)

Comment: it almost sounds like that could be an issue with your connection from the tube to the tank.  after trying a new tank, see if that corrected the issue.  if it didn't, i would try to replace the tube and connection.

Comment: I've noticed problems when you do it that way ... although it's usually that the tank refuses to let out a significant amount of gas.  But this might be the regulator refusing to open, so there's more pressure at the connections before it.  I'd recommend closing both the tank and grill, turning on the tank first, then the grill.  But as there's also a leak, replacing the tank would be a good idea.  If that's not not an option, I'd pack around the valve with some sort of adhesive putty (like airdam, although that's for vaccuum, not pressure) and possibly a layer of duct tape to keep it down.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 parts to the question are unrelated.  The valve on the top of the tank will allow gas to flow to the grill when open.  The burner valves allow the gas to continue on to the burner(s) when open.  All the valves do is let the gas go by when open.  When you replace the tank YOU are making the connection from the tank to the hose which feeds the grille.  If gas leaks from that connection you have incorrectly made the connection.  It's likely you have improperly aligned the two pieces and believed that the connection was tight when it actually could not go any farther.  The grille instructions should say to check for leaks after changing the tank.  You can do this by mixing dish soap and water and applying with a brush or rag on the fittings with the valve open and the burners closed.  If there is a leak you will see bubbles form.  Then close the tank and fix the connection.  If you get stuck take pictures with your phone and show your propane people and they should be able to guide you.  PROPANE IS AN EXPLOSIVE GAS.  Keep the tank valve closed (turned clockwise all the way down) when not in use and if you're not sure what you are doing, DON'T!